# How correctly send email and close smtp connection in nodemailer?

Tags: javascript, node.js, smtp, nodemailer

In my `Node.js` application I use [nodemailer](https://nodemailer.com/) library to send emails by `SMTP`.

As you can see from the code I have array called `employees`. That array has 2000 email address.

When I use code below application send only 10 email and then raise error `Error: Invalid greeting. response=421 4.7.0 mailrelay1.***.** Error: too many connections from xxx.xx.xx.xxx`.

It seems to me that every sending operation don't close the channel, even though I explicitly specified `.close()` method.

```
const express = require('express');
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
const forAsync = require('for-async');

let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    host: process.env.SMTP_HOST,
    port: parseInt(process.env.SMTP_PORT, 10),
    secure: false,
    tls: {
        rejectUnauthorized: false
    }
});

const router = express.Router();

router.post('/employees', function(request, response) {
    const employees = [***];

    forAsync(employees, (employee) => {
        return new Promise(resolve => {
            // Setup email options.
            const options = {
                from: process.env.EMAIL,
                to: employee,
                subject: "System Alert",
                html: html
            };

            return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                setTimeout(() => {
                    transporter.sendMail(options, (error) => {
                        if(error) {
                            console.log(error);
                            reject(error);
                        } else {
                            resolve();
                        }
                   });

                   transporter.close();
                }, 5000);
            }).then(() => {
                resolve();
            }).catch(error => {
                console.log(error);
            });

        });

    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look into sending a [pool of emails](https://community.nodemailer.com/delivering-bulk-mail/).

To do this toggle the ['pool' option](https://nodemailer.com/smtp/pooled/) when you create your transport:

```js
let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
  pool: true,
  host: process.env.SMTP_HOST,
  port: parseInt(process.env.SMTP_PORT, 10),
  secure: false,
  tls: {
    rejectUnauthorized: false
  }
});
```

Comment: Hello! I added option which you recommended. Unfortunately I see the following error: `Error: Connection pool was closed`. After that error I removed `transporter.close();` which I used earlier. Finally I see such error after 10 email: `Error: Mail command failed: 450 4.7.1 Error: too much mail from xxx.xx.xxx.xxx`.

Comment: It seems like removing the `transporter.close()` line was necessary for the pooling to work properly. It also seems like there are other limits related to rate of requests from a single IP. Try using the other options on [here](https://nodemailer.com/smtp/pooled/) to match the limits you are facing.

Comment: I tried to play with different options. Unfortunately none of them helped me. If restriction costs on the SMTP server on which I have no access, only `RabbitMQ` could help me for my opinion. Do you have any ideas?